# BSOD errors persisting across hard drives and fresh installs

Tags: windows-10, memory, bsod

Just finished building my new PC and it starts up. Unfortunately I'm getting BSOD errors. Specifically I'm getting `Memory Management Error`, `Attempted Write to Readonly Memory`, `IRQL Not Less or Equal`, and `Kernel security check failure`. In about that order of prevalence.

I tried an install on a fresh hard drive, but found that this did not solve the issue. In addition I've tried to debug the problem by trying to reproduce it to no avail. Sometimes it'll happen instantly after startup. Sometimes it'll happen after half an hour of use. Sometimes it'll happen when I'm installing something, but often things will install fine. CPU temp is `30-40C`. Only things I've got installed are Steam and Chrome. BIOS version is `F5`.

Really at a loss for how to even debug this. Any guidance appreciated.

System details here: https://pcpartpicker.com/list/6GYx3F

Comment: Just wondering, have you gotten the "Page Fault" error too?

Comment: @GeorgeTian Not yet at least. I'm running memory diagnostic, but nothing so far.

Comment: These error codes seem to point to a similar problem. What is your Intel Management Engine Interface driver version? (Device manager > System devices > Intel (R) Management Engine Interface)

Comment: @GeorgeTian Will be ~15 minutes before I can answer, memory diagnostic is about half over.

Comment: @GeorgeTian Nothing like that shows up in my System devices.

Comment: @GeorgeTian I guess it's not surprising since I don't have any Intel parts in my machine.

Comment: Oh oops, I just assumed you had Intel. Sorry, I can't be of further help.

Comment: @GeorgeTian No worries. Parts list is under the system details link.

Comment: What memory tests did you run? Tried a few hours with memtest (as found on most linux iso's)? Do memory sticks match (if more than one)?

Comment: @Xen2050 Just standard memory diagnostic. Sticks do match. Should I try a different test?

Comment: I don't know your standard diagnostic, aside from a POST test, but do try the one I mentioned, `memtest`. It's on every Ubuntu live ISO I've ever seen, virtually every linux ISO in fact. It usually just starts running on it's own (maybe after a brief "Press xxx for safe mode" or similar message) and if it doesn't say there's any errors after an hour or two the memory's probably fine. Running overnight is an idea for a more in-depth check, but problems from those errors should be infrequent too. PS. is your windows install (copy or media) confirmed good? Verified it with a hash or something?

Comment: If the BSOD's appear quickly, and there's more than one memory stick, you could just try removing a sick & wait for a BSOD, then try with the other(s), if that's easier than getting memtest a linux ISO to boot/run. (It must have windows options to run it, I've just never needed them). --- It could be a power or MB or other hardware issue too, removing/swapping & testing may be the quickest way to narrow it down (if you've got spare power/video/etc). Wall power's an idea too, bad powerbar or UPS, house wiring, that's the clutching at straws idea.

Comment: update to BIOS F6, latest AGESA fixes RAM issues

Comment: @magicandre1981 Any idea where I'd find an F6 download? Can't find it on the Aorus website

Comment: Aorus? open gigabyte page: https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-AX370-Gaming-5-rev-10#support-dl

Comment: @magicandre1981 Ah, they're the motherboard manufacturer, and they host some of the BIOS versions, but not all of them. Thanks for the link. I'll be able to check this later today.

Comment: Aorus is the branding name for gaming hardware (motherboard, laptops) of gigabyte

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thank you! This was exactly the issue. Upgraded to F6 and no issues any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AMD Ryzen is a new CPU architecture and had some RAM incompatibilities at the start. [AMD improved this a lot since AMD Generic Encapsulated System Architecture (AGESA) v1.0.0.6](https://community.amd.com/community/gaming/blog/2017/05/25/community-update-4-lets-talk-dram):

> AGESA 1.0.0.6 officially adds 26 new parameters that can improve the
>   compatibility and reliability of DRAM, especially for memory that does
>   not follow the industry-standard JEDEC specifications (e.g. faster
>   than 2667, manual overclocking, or XMP2 profiles).

For your [Gigabyte GA-AX370-GAMING 5](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-AX370-Gaming-5-rev-10#kf) motherboard the first [BIOS that includes those fixes is F6](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-AX370-Gaming-5-rev-10#support-dl). So update to this BIOS/UEFI version to fix the issues.

Answer (score 1):

This was referenced in magicandre1981's comment, but wanted to make sure it's documented in an answer. This is an error with BIOS version F5. Upgrading the BIOS to version F6 should resolve this issue satisfactorily.

The download link for BIOS F6 can be found [here](https://gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-AX370-Gaming-5-rev-10#support-dl). To install it, just download the appropriate BIOS version onto a FAT-formatted flash drive, then boot into `Q-flash` (Hold `Del` key during startup). You'll then be guided through a clear GUI for BIOS update.

Comment: I also posted as answer with some background and an AMD blog entry